# Collecting unique sorted vectors

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have hundred millions of sorted vectors containing floating numbers, the size of each array are the same and reasonably small(less than ten), I need to collect the unique vectors out of such vectors,

```
    vec1 = {1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}
    vec2 = {1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7}
    vec2 = {1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6}

...

    SomeTree ={vec1, vec2, vec3 ...}
```

an array is considered the "same" as another only if every elements are numerically the same(up to some precision), Is there any special tree or other data structure suitable for such purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is called [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::vector<double>> s{
        { 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7 },
        { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8 },
        { 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7 },
        { 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 },
        { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8 },
        { 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7 },
        { 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8 },
        { 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 },
        { 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 },
    };    
}
```

It's likely that you will want to deeply analyze the `Compare` parameter of the template, in order to have a definition of `less` that fits your requirements.

Comment: Grazie! I understand the transitive issue, but if I use the default less operator, I hope it works fine at least for the example in your answer, i.e. { 1.0, 1.1, 1.3} = { 1.0, 1.1, 1.3}, is it true?

Comment: @lorniper True. It works perfectly for exact same doubles. As soon as those double are obtained by some computation, they will likely not be exactly the same.

Comment: @lorniper Remember to accept the answer if it is correct, so that other people will know that its ok.